# geoalchemy2, WKT on local env, EWKT in production

Tags: well-known-text, geoalchemy-2

I am working with an REST API for geospatial data using flask. When working on it locally everything has been fine. I am posting WKT data to the local server to create new objects. But if I send WKT to the production server I get:

> "psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue: Geometry SRID (0) does not
> match column SRID (4326)"

The table definition is identical in both environment.
Ideally I dont want to send EWKT to the server in production, just WKT. But I am confused to why there is a difference? I am using the same geoalchemy2 versions both locally and in production. Is there a way to control if the server need WKT or EWKT somehow that I have missed?

Comment: Could you add your code when you add data to the postgres server? How many geometry columns do you have?

Comment: Not sure code example actually make much difference. This is basically my commit objekt to the db. Without SRID it fail on prod server (psycopg2 that complains), whereas locally it works fine. my_geom_sqlachemy_obj = {"geom":"SRID=4326;Point((10 50)}

Comment: What if you give it srid=0, and then assign the srid 4326 in the PostGIS later?